# Return sum of a number (positive or negative)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, digits

I need to make a function that takes a number and returns sum of it's digits, if the number is negative the first digit should be considered negative when adding numbers, this is what I have:

```
var arrx = [];
var oper;
var others = 0;

function sumDigits(num) {
    // your code here
    var y = num.toString();
    var c = y.split("");
    c.forEach((h) => arrx.push(Number(h)) );
    if (num < 0){
        oper = -arrx[0];
        for (var z = 1; z < arrx.length; z++){
            others += arrx[z];
        }

        return others + oper;
    }

    return arrx.reduce((a,b) => a+b);
}

sumDigits(1234);
```

When given negative number, function returns NaN, what's the problem ?

Comment: Why do you push the digits to an array when `c` is already one?

Comment: I suggest developing an algorithm that works directly with numbers rather than converting the number to a String. Can you think of a way to get the ones digit from a number? How do you get the rest of the number other than the ones digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use optimized and short version of `sumDigits()` function:

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  var isNeg = num < 0,   // check whether the number is negative
      numbers = (isNeg? String(num).slice(1) : String(num)).split('').map(Number);
  if (isNeg) numbers[0] *= -1;   // 'recovering' the number's sign

  return numbers.reduce(function(a,b){ return a + b; });
}

console.log(sumDigits(1234));
console.log(sumDigits(-951));
```

Comment: i am having trouble understanding the value in numbers. If I was to write it out, would it look like this?
`if(isNeg) { String(num).slice(1); } else { String(num); } numbers.split('').map(Number);`
?

Comment: @FrancisNgo, you forgot to assign the result of condition to `numbers`

Comment: `var numbers = if(isNeg) { String(num).slice(1); } else { String(num); } numbers.split('').map(Number);` ?

Comment: no, `if(isNeg) { numbers  = String(num).slice(1); } else { numbers  = String(num); } `. But it doesn't look much better than original

Answer (score 1):

In case of negative number, the first char is '-' the **minus** symbol. When you are trying to convert it to number, you are getting `NaN`. After that if you try to add `NaN` to any number the result would be `NaN`.

As a resolution, you need to ignore the first digit if the number is negative.

So, you can make a code change like

```
if(z === 1){
    others = others - arrx[z];
    }else{
     others += arrx[z];
      }
```

and also changing the return in case of negative numbers to `return others;`

Following code should work.

```js
var arrx = [];
var oper;
var others = 0;

function sumDigits(num) {
 // your code here

var y = num.toString();

var c = y.split("");

c.forEach((h) => arrx.push(Number(h)) );

if (num < 0){


for (var z = 1; z < arrx.length; z++){

  if(z === 1){
    others = others - arrx[z];
    }else{
     others += arrx[z];
      }

}

return others;
}

return arrx.reduce((a,b) => a+b);

}
console.log(sumDigits(-1234));
```

Comment: If I ignore it the result won't be good in case of a negative number.

Comment: Check the code in post, it should work, it is pretty much the same, except the `return` and `if` condition.